# Cannot use phtml template twice in content block

Tags: magento

I want to setup a Magento page like this:

```
<h2>Title</h2>

{{block type="catalog/navigation" category_id="5" template="/catalog/navigation/subcategorylisting-distinctive.phtml"}}
<h2>Title</h2>

{{block type="catalog/navigation" category_id="9" template="/catalog/navigation/subcategorylisting-distinctive.phtml"}}
<h2>Title</h2>

{{block type="catalog/navigation" category_id="38" template="/catalog/navigation/subcategorylisting-distinctive.phtml"}}
```

My problem is, that the template i am calling can only be used once in a site. If I'm trying to call it a second time, I get a blank page.

```
<div id="categories">

    <div class="col_full">

        <div class="products-grid row first last odd" >

            <?php

            function getImageUrl($category)

            {

                $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());

                $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');

                $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);

                $url = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl();

                return $url;

            };


            //Get the Current Category
            $category = $this->getData('category_id');
            $_maincategorylisting=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category);


            // Iterate all categories in store

            foreach ($_maincategorylisting as $_category):


                // If category is Active

                if($_category->getIsActive()):


                    // Load the actual category object for this category

                    $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());


                    // Load a random product from this category

                    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($cur_category);

                    $products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))->limit(100);


                    $products->load();


                    // This a bit of a fudge - there's only one element in the collection

                    $_product = null;


                    foreach ( $products as $_product ) {}


                    if(isset($_product)):

                        ?>


                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3" >

                            <div class="img-responsive"><p><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>" class="product-image">


                                        <?php

                                        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');

                                        $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);

                                        ?>


                                        <?

                                        // If there is an image set for the category - Display it

                                        if($_imgUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):?>

                                            <img src="<?php echo $_imgUrl ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />

                                        <?php endif; ?>


                                        <?

                                        // If there is not a image set for that Category - Display a random product Image

                                        if(!$_imgUrl):


                                            // Let's load the category Model and grab the product collection of that category


                                            $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getProductCollection();

                                            $product_collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))->limit(1);


                                            // Now let's loop through the product collection and print the ID of every product

                                            foreach($product_collection as $product) {


                                                // Get the product ID

                                                $product_id = $product->getId();


                                                // Load the full product model based on the product ID


                                                $full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);


                                                // Now that we loaded the full product model, let's access all of it's data


                                                // Let's get the Product Name


                                                $product_name = $full_product->getName();


                                                // Let's get the Product URL path


                                                $product_url = $full_product->getProductUrl();


                                                // Let's get the Product Image URL


                                                $product_image_url = $full_product->getImageUrl();


                                                // Let's print the product information we gathered and continue onto the next one

                                            } //End For Each

                                            ?>

                                            <img src="<?php echo $product_image_url; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    </a>

                            </div>

                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>">

                                <h2 class="text-center product-name" ><?php echo $_category->getName()?></a></h2>

                            <? if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()):?>

                                <p class="category-description">

                                    <?php // echo $_description ?></p>

                            <?php   endif ?>

                        </div>

                    <?php

                    endif;

                endif;

            endforeach;

            ?>

        </div>

        <br clear=all>

    </div>

</div>
```

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong? Do I have to close some argument I am missing? Appriciate your Help!

Comment: I scrolled a bit through your code, it's not related to your question but let me give you an advice: never use `load()` in a loop. You iterate over a loaded category collection, load each category again in the loop and in this loop, do the same again for products. This is horribly unperformant. Instead, use methods like `addAttributeToSelect` on the collection to make sure everything that you need is already loaded the first time (this is one big database query instead of one plus one per category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a function in the template. A function can only be defined once.

### Doing it right™

Don't use functions. The Magento way would be to either define your own block that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` and add the function as method to this block or to move the function into a helper class.

### Quick'n'Dirty Workaround

Create the function as a closure instead of a normal global function:

```
$getImageUrl = function($category) {
    // ...
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$getImageUrl($category)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turned out I don't need the whole function for my purpose.